# software 4x4tb raid 5 win 2008 r2 to 2012, server down

Tags: windows, migration, raid5

I have a server fujitsu econel 100 with 4x4tb in raid 5 configuration (software based with windows server 2008 r2)
now the server is down (PSU and motherboard KO) and I will buy a new machine to recover the array.

If I put the entire array in the new machine, will it be able to automatically recognize the raid 5 array and keep the structure and the data?

do I need to put the 4 disks in the same order (speaking of onboard sata port)?

if I install win 2012, will I have a problem? do I need win 2008 r2 as the original machine?

Comment: Is your boot volume on this RAID? It will depend greatly on the hardware in the new server vs the hardware in the old if it works.

Comment: After you fix it, you may want to do some reading on why raid5 on large disks is a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: ok then... I will try putting the array in a new machine with different hardware but same OS and give it a try.